# Deezer API in Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, deezer

I'm building an app accessing Deezer's API.

Using Günter's tip of using jsonp, if I use Deezer's API like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DeezerService{

  constructor(private _jsonp:Jsonp){
  }

  dzSearch(){
    console.log('Testing dzSearch() init');
    return this._jsonp.request('https://api.deezer.com/search/artist/?q=deftones&output=jsonp', {method:'Get'})
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}
```

I get an API OK 200 response, but it still won't work as I get errors saying:

1. EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:
   https://api.deezer.com/search/artist/?q=deftones&output=json
2. Uncaught Response {_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke
   callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers:
   Headers…}

**Original:** Using their Javascript SDK, I've gained access to it using:

```
declare var DZ : any;

@Injectable()
export class DeezerService{

  constructor(private _http:Http){
    new DZ.init({
      appId  : 'APPID',
      channelUrl : 'http://localhost:4200/src/channel.html'
    });
  }

  dzSearch(){
    console.log('Testing dzSearch() init');
    DZ.api('/album/12720342/tracks', function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
    }); 
  }
}
```

This works, but this is not how I want to use it as I can't pass variables around. I want to use the REST API as a service, just like in the Eduonix Course on Angular2. Haven't tested posting to firebase's db in the function but that isn't performant as well, but I guess that will work.

Is there something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: Yup, you need to change the server configuration ;-) Their script perhaps uses JSONP to work around the limitation but JSONP has quite some limitations.

Comment: How would i go about implementing JSONP?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Jsonp-class.html. It works similar to `HttpModule`. There are several questions with answers on SO for examples.

Comment: Günter, I've been able to implement jsonp but I'm still getting errors. I've updated my question, you can find the entire log there.

Comment: I haven't used JSONP myself, I just know that it can be used to work around CORS issues. Another way is to connect the foreign server from a server you control or where you web page is loaded from and allow the client to make the request to your server instead while your server forwards to the CORS-protected server and then forward the response to the client.

Comment: I've read about that approach somewhere else as well. I might be forced to try it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What the server does when you ask it to return JSONP is basically return JSON with JavaScript code wrapped around it. This JavaScript is usually a function. This way a function that is already defined in the JavaScript environment can manipulate the JSON data.

A typical JSON payload would normally look like this:

```
{“Id”: 565, “Name”: “Foo”, “LastName: “Bar”}
```

The equivalent JSONP payload will look something like this:

```
functionName({“Id”: 565, “Name”: “Foo”, “LastName: “Bar”})
```

The server providing the JSON data offers the requesting website the ability to name the function. The problem in your code is that you ask the server to return JSONP but you do not provide it a name the function should have. This means the server returns something like this:

```
({“Id”: 565, “Name”: “Foo”, “LastName: “Bar”})
```

In the Angular2 JsonpModule the function that has to be called is named 'JSONP_CALLBACK'. You should pass this name to the server.

Your Angular2 code could then be:

```
constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) { }

getTest(): Observable<any> {
  return this.jsonp
    .get('https://api.deezer.com/chart?output=jsonp&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
    .map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res:Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || {};
}
```